# how to call constructor from static constructor in c# so that normal constructor is executed first

Tags: c#, constructor

I want to call a normal constructor from a static constructor, so that i can execute the normal constructor before static constructor .
please help me out.

Comment: so just... call an instance constructor (`new()` an object) at the start of the static constructor? but: it is unclear *why* this would matter - it sounds like an unusual scenario that should perhaps have more explanation as to what you are doing and why this matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static constructor *will* start executing before the instance constructor, but you can still call the instance constructor... and indeed this is a common approach for implementing a singleton. For example:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    // I'd usually make it a property in real code, backed by a readonly field
    public static readonly Singleton Instance;

    static Singleton()
    {
        Instance = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
        // Only invoked from the static constructor
    }
}
```